# Scalar product between an original and shifted solid state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Suppose, we have a perfect cubic brick with no imperfections and a rectangular lattice (w=l=h=10cm). Suppose I shift this brick by $\Delta x = 1mm$. What is a scalar product of wave functions before and after the shift?

Can I estimate it like
$$
<\psi_1|\psi_2> \sim (C e^{-\frac{(\Delta x / N_{1D})^2}{2\sigma^2}})^{N_{all}}
$$
?

Where $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$ are wave function of the brick before and after the shift, $N_{all}$ - total number of atoms in the brick, $N_{1D}$ - number of atoms along the dimensions we use for shifting, $\sigma$ is a size of an atom (1A), $C$ is the normalization of the exponent?

Here I assume that the brick is basically a gas of $N$ atoms, and ignore any vibration, rotational, any other degrees of freedom, and electrons.

Does this approximation make sense (like gives a correct order) or completely wrong?

Or can I estimate it assuming that the wave function of the brick is just an exponent with some width (not sure what the width is)?

If not, how to estimate this scalar product in an ideal case?